# How do I remove a panel from the ceiling of my side porch?

Tags: ceiling, soffit, porch

I have an uncovered side porch attached to the my brick ranch home.  I noticed that parts of my roof are sagging and it is getting worse.  I also noticed that some flashing around my chimney looks bad and I am hoping that I am not storing pools of water above my ceiling.

I'd like to remove some of the panels and have a look.  But I can't figure out how to do this without ruining the materials.  If I can help it I do not want to damage anything that I cannot easily put back.

Anyone have any ideas?  I attached a picture of the sagging roof as well as some pictures of the edges.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need the tool shown here: (or just 'pop' it out by hand) [Is there a quick, non-intrusive way to see what's under vinyl siding?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58146/is-there-a-quick-non-intrusive-way-to-see-whats-under-vinyl-siding)

Answer (score 1):

These videos walk you through removing and replacing vinyl siding components:

1. [This video walks you through the steps for removing soffit panels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZypaC8PsT4).
2. [This video walks you through the steps for removing and replacing vinyl soffit panels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1A2D8tuNlc).
3. [This video walks you through the installation process for vinyl soffit and trim so you can have a deeper understanding of what you're working with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yme7R4GLW84).
4. [This video walks you through the steps for removing and replacing vinyl siding siding so you can know what you're working around or if you find you need to pull some of the siding to get at the pieces you're focusing on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FmYRzCgL-8&t=199s).

Comment: Jon,  link only answers are discouraged here.  Links are fine if you are **using them to support a *detailed* explanation** of the advise that you are giving. **I.E.** Explain how to address the problem and then provide a link.  *Please take the tour and **read** this* https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like need a vinyl siding tool called a zip tool. You can go to pretty much any home improvement store that deals with vinyl siding and ask for a zip tool too disconnect the panels. It looks like the nailing tab for the vinyl siding is missing nail door come lose so you should just be able to use the tool to disconnect the panels and and mail them in the nail strips.

Comment: Orange big box does not have them in stores but check online.